# Why do you need an unlikely integer in paginating?

Tags: pagination

The [`paginate_links` Codex function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) has some sample code that's being reposted all over the net.

It has a section that uses a variable called `$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer`:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

And is used in `str_replace` in the `echo paginate_links` function.

Is this some form of encapsulation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note the `get_pagenum_link( $big )`: This will create an URL (*not* a link) based on the number provided in the first parameter.

That function is used to get the basic pattern for the URL, and the high integer is used here, because:

1. You must provide an integer as argument.
2. The resulting URL is filtered with `apply_filters('get_pagenum_link', $result)` and might be changed by plugins. This risk is slightly higher for numbers *matching existing pages,* for example when a plugin implements separate titles for sub-pages.

So this is just a … dirty convention, a signal to other plugins: Don’t change that please! I think `PHP_INT_MAX` would have been better, but still ugly. And I wonder how many plugin developers *know* that.

The number is then replaced with the placeholder needed in `paginate_links()`.

What you see here is an **incomplete API**. Try to learn something from this example – do not release incomplete APIs, or your docs will look embarrassing. :)

Comment: I agree PHP_INT_MAX would have been better IMO, but would have confused me at the time more. I really like your explanation, it confirms that I was thinking along the right lines. I just didn't want to make any assumptions.

Comment: So is this used *only* in the case of a filter on `get_pagenum_link` affecting *existing* page numbers? (since `paginate_links()` uses `get_pagenum_link()` by default anyway). Seems like an extreme edge case to me, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Cai Looks it has been a real problem once. Code bases maintained over a long time tend to be filled with workarounds for edge cases.

Comment: It [looks like](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset?new=28785%40trunk%2Fsrc%2Fwp-includes%2Fgeneral-template.php&old=28671%40trunk%2Fsrc%2Fwp-includes%2Fgeneral-template.php) `paginate_links()` didn't always use `get_pagenum_link()` by default so I'm wondering if this is a convention from before then and if the 'unlikely integer' is really needed (or if the real workaround was simply `get_pagenum_link()`)?